# How do you load a select field with pre-selected items when the Chosen module is installed/enabled?

Tags: forms

How do you load a select field with pre-selected items when the Chosen module is installed/enabled?

I am using the following code.

```php
$my_list = array('item1' = 'item1', 'item2' = 'item2', 'item3' = 'item3');
$form['list_info']['my_list'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Select a list to manage:'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $my_list,
  '#default_value' => $my_list,
);
```

The select field shows up empty. Clicking it reveals the items and I can select them, but I need the field to show up with the items selected.

Comment: Set `#options => array_keys(array_filter($my_list))`

Comment: @AykeshK That will cause the actual passed values for to the submit handler to be removed by setting the array to an indexed one of the keys (array_keys) and remove empty values of wich there shouldnt even be any after array_keys (array_filter).
But it won't solve the problem in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your select field is currently only accepting one selected option. This is why it won't allow an array as a default value. (It expects a string or an integer).

The following select field allows more than a selected option.

```php
$form['list_info']['my_list'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Select a list to manage:'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $my_list,
  '#default_value' => $my_list,
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
);
```